# Combination of If and copy fails with syntax incorrect

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-console

I'm trying to create a .bat file that uses a Parameter to define which copy it should do.

I tried the if without copy (an echo instead) which worked fine, and I tried the copy command which also worked fine, but whenever I tried to Combine both in the .bat file I get:
***The Syntax of the command is incorrect.***

```
@echo off

if "%1%"=="P1" (copy /y c:\Meldung\Mel_properties_p1.bak c:\Meldung\gsa.properties)
if "%1%"=="P2" (copy /y c:\Meldung\Mel_properties_p2.bak c:\Meldung\Mel.properties)

@echo on
```

Even after looking at the tech docu I didn't see anything that Looks wrong to me. Thusmy question: What is wrong here? And why?

Comment: Is this supposed to read, `If /I "%~1"=="P1"` and `If /I "%~1"=="P2"`?

Answer (score 1):

your parameter is `%1`, not `%1%`, which is syntax for a environment variable (which doesn't exist, as it translates to `%1` and a single `%`), so the parser tries to translate according to it's rules:

```
if <Parameter1><variable>
```

where it tries to evaluate a variable named `"=="P1" (copy /y c` (invalid variablename anyway) up to the colon, which has a special meaning (see substring substitution `set /?`). This is bound to fail.

With `echo on` you get the line, as the parser tries to execute it:

```
if "P1\Meldung\Mel_properties_p1.bak c:\Meldung\gsa.properties)
```

Which obviously is no correct `if` syntax.

Solution: simply use the correct syntax for the parameter, and it works:

```
if "%1"=="P1" (copy /y c:\Meldung\Mel_properties_p1.bak c:\Meldung\gsa.properties)
if "%1"=="P2" (copy /y c:\Meldung\Mel_properties_p2.bak c:\Meldung\Mel.properties)
```

Note: I recommend using `if /i "%~1" ...` where `/i` makes it case insensitive (also `p1` will be recognized) and `%~1` removes quotes around the parameter, should they exist. (without, you might end with `if ""P1"" ...` which will be trouble)

Comment: Yes. Syntax is `if <value1> <comparator> <value2> command`, so the command even *has* to be on the same (logical) line. Although you could split it into several *physical* lines like `if a == b (` and next line `echo equal` and next line `)`. This is called a code block and at least the `(` has to be on the same physical line as the `if`.

Comment: I asked as I had troubles until I moved the "copy...." part into the next line (which made no sense to me)